# Dynamically resize UITableViewCell at runtime on tvOS

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, uicollectionview, tvos

I currently have a `UIViewController` with the following hierarchy:

```
UIViewController
-- UIView
---- UITableView
------ UITableViewCell
-------- UICollectionView
---------- UICollectionViewCell
-------- UIView
---------- UIStackView
------------ UILabel
------------ UILabel
```

So basically, I have a `UITableViewCell`, containing an `UICollectionView` and an `UIView`, with the following constraints defined in Interface Builder:

```
UICollectionView.leading = Superview.leading
UICollectionView.trailing = Superview.trailing
UICollectionView.top = Superview.top
UICollectionView.bottom = UIView.top
UIView.leading = Superview.leading
UIView.trailing = Superview.trailing
UIView.bottom = Superview.bottom
```

The `UICollectionView` is also set up with a horizontal flow layout.

In my ViewController, I have also overridden the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` datasource function for the `UITableView`.

The result is a vertically scrolling list of `UITableViewCell`s, and each `UITableViewCell` will have a horizontally scrolling list of `UIImageView`s. The `UIView` and its two `UILabel`s will display relevant information to the `UIImageView` when it is focused.

What I am trying to achieve is to hide the `UIView` containing the two `UILabel`s when the focus moves to a different `UITableViewCell`. I am able to trap and detect the change in focus by overriding the `didUpdateFocusInContext` function. I am able to reduce the height of the previously-focused `UITableViewCell` in the `UICollectionViewDelegate`, however, the gap between the previously-focused and currently-focused `UITableViewCell`s remain unchanged.

Attempts to set the `UITableView.RowHeight` to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, setting `UITableView.EstimatedRowHeight` to an arbitrary figure, removing the overridden `heightForRowAtIndexPath` function, causes the `UICollectionView`s to not load at all.

Does anyone have a good suggestion on what I could try?

**Edit:** Sample source code

**ViewController**

```
// ==== ViewController.swift ====
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let cellIdentifier = "\(CVTableViewCell.self)"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupControls()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        setupControls()
    }

    func setupControls() {
        setupTableView()
    }

    func setupTableView() {
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        // causes collectionView in CVTableViewCell to not load            
//        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
//        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200

        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: cellIdentifier, bundle: nil),
                           forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 316.0 + 106.0 // 316.0 for image height, 106.0 for labelContainerView
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {    
        guard let dequeuedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? CVTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("Unable to dequeue cell")
        }

        return dequeuedCell
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canFocusRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

**CVTableViewCell**

```
// ==== CVTableViewCell.swift ====
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CVTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelContainerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelContainerStackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondLabel: UILabel!

    let cellIdentifier = "\(CVCollectionViewCell.self)"

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        setupControls()
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        setupControls()
    }

    func setupControls() {
        setupTableViewCell()
        setupCollectionView()
        setupLabelContainerView()
        setupLabelContainerStackView()
        setupLabels()
    }

    func setupTableViewCell() {
        contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
    }

    func setupCollectionView() {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 316.0, height: 316.0)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 50.0

        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        collectionView.clipsToBounds = false
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: cellIdentifier, bundle: nil),
                                forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }

    func setupLabelContainerView() {
        labelContainerView.backgroundColor = .clear
    }

    func setupLabelContainerStackView() {
        labelContainerStackView.backgroundColor = .clear
        labelContainerStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    }

    func setupLabels() {
        firstLabel.text = "Look at me"
        secondLabel.text = "I refuse to go away"
    }
}

extension CVTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let dequeuedCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? CVCollectionViewCell else {
            fatalError("Unable to dequeue cell")
        }

        dequeuedCell.imageView.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = true
        dequeuedCell.imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "stackoverflow")

        return dequeuedCell
    }
}

extension CVTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        super.didUpdateFocus(in: context, with: coordinator)

        // if next focused view is within current collectionview, show labelContainerView
        // else hide
        if let cell = context.nextFocusedView as? CVCollectionViewCell,
            let _ = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) {
            labelContainerView.isHidden = false
        } else {
            labelContainerView.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

**CVCollectionViewCell**

```
// ==== CVCollectionViewCell.swift ====
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CVCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        setupControls()
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        setupControls()
    }

    func setupControls() {
        setupImageView()
    }

    func setupCollectionViewCell() {
        backgroundColor = .clear
    }

    func setupImageView() {
        imageView.image = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: First? (And maybe you've tried this already.) Make the issue more simpler your view hierarchy. Maybe start with a `UIView` that contains a `UITableView` and get *that* working with variable cell height. I know it's very basic - but then add in your collection view, labels, etc. And **no** not in your project - a new one. (If you think it's due to layout, make sure you add what's needed there.) If you can get that project working, you should either (a) hopefully found your issue or (b) have something *very* specific to have us try.

Comment: @dfd Actually, I have tried that, and with a UI that has static content, or at least content that the UI is capable of 'knowing' the dimensions of before drawing. However, the UI that I'm driving towards is invariably more complex, and has a certain number of unknowns that will only be obtained asynchronously. I do have the luxury of specifying each row's individual height, which is why I have overridden the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` function, but that's just about as far as I can get.

Comment: I understand. Can you post some code that I can duplicate the issue?

Comment: @dfd Sure thing, let me try to water down my code and I’ll post an edit with my code samples. Thanks!

Comment: @dfd Sample source code posted!